# Panorama extend rectangle over 3 pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, rectangles, panorama-control

Is it possible to extend a rectangle or a image over 3pages of the panorama view, at the moment it is just on the first page, but I want to extend it over the others.

I am not sure what items margin or width I should set, the panorama or panorama item or rectangle, I have tried al 3 but still not working

---

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="third item" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Double wide Panorama with large image placeholders-->
            <Grid >
                <ListBox x:Name="lst">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Margin="10" Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Red"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>

        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

I have tried this code above, but it does not display anything?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
in panoramaitem just put Orientation="Horizontal" and if you are using listbox just set itempanel with stackpanal orientation horizonta.

```
  <controls:PanoramaItem Orientation="Horizontal" Header="item1">
            <Grid >
                <ListBox x:Name="lst">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Margin="10" Source="{Binding}" Width="200" Height="200"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```